# Mosby MVP - FragmentStatePagerAdapter - NPE

Tags: android, mosby

For my new app i want to use the Mosby Framework.
At the moment i have an activity with two tabs and it works fine for my.

Now i want to implement a new activity with 12 tabs and when i want to switch to a new tab i get a NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Presenter returned from getPresenter() is null
at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.delegate.MvpInternalDelegate.getPresenter(MvpInternalDelegate.java:76)
at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.delegate.MvpInternalDelegate.detachView(MvpInternalDelegate.java:70)
```

My working activity use the FragmenPagerAdapter.
The new Activity should use FragmenStatePagerAdapter. At this point i get a NPE.

Here is my code

```
//MainActivity
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupViewPager();
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    @Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.activity_navigation;
    }

    private void setupViewPager() {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
        String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -12);

        for (int i = -12; i <= 12; i++) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);
            adapter.addFragment(months[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(11);
        //viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    }

    public static class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List<String> fragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new OverviewFragmentBuilder(1).build();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentTitles.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitles.get(position);
        }

        private void addFragment(String title) {
            fragmentTitles.add(title);
        }
    }

// Fragment
public class OverviewFragment extends MvpFragment<OverviewView, OverviewPresenter>
    implements OverviewView {

    private OverviewComponent component;

    @Arg
    public int month;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentArgs.inject(this);
        component = DaggerOverviewComponent
            .builder()
            .appComponent(((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getAppComponent())
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public OverviewPresenter createPresenter() {
        Log.d("wtf", "ever called??");
        return component.presenter();
    }
```

My Log "wtf" in the createPresenter is never called... 
Here a my Dagger-2 component

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface OverviewComponent {
    OverviewPresenter presenter();
}
```

Can anybody help me? I think that the framework works fine and i make a silly mistake... ;D

```
12-24 15:04:03.800 2547-2547/com.test.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.test.testapp, PID: 2547
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Presenter returned from getPresenter() is null
                                                                                 at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.delegate.MvpInternalDelegate.getPresenter(MvpInternalDelegate.java:76)
                                                                                 at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.delegate.MvpInternalDelegate.detachView(MvpInternalDelegate.java:70)
                                                                                 at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.delegate.FragmentMvpDelegateImpl.onDestroyView(FragmentMvpDelegateImpl.java:71)
                                                                                 at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.MvpFragment.onDestroyView(MvpFragment.java:106)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:2167)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1141)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1345)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:708)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1778)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:871)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:841)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1115)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$1.onClick(TabLayout.java:665)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Which version of Mosby are you using? Can you also please post the full error stacktrace

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0. I added the full stacktrace. Thx!

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the `OverviewFragment`? Are you using other Fragments? From the stacktrace i can say that a MvpFragment has been created successfully and a presenter has been used by the fragment (`createPresenter()` should have been called otherwise a NPE should have been already thrown in `Fragment.onCreateView()`). However, when the Fragment get's destroyed (`Fragment.onDestroyView()`) the presenter is null (Mosby want's to call `presenter.detachView()` but presenter is null).
MvpFragment has a protected field `presenter`. Are you misusing / overriding this field somewhere?

Comment: The `ViewPager` works fine if i use the `Fragment`class. [Maybe the full source of my Activity helps](https://gist.github.com/T0bbes/308b5d767a9972135cbd) I really don't know why this does not working...

Comment: What happens if you use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (without STATE) ?

Comment: The same. I don't know why.. it is the same code of my other working activity except that i don't create "dynamic" tabs. In my working activity i save the Fragments in a `List<Fragment>` and in `getItem()' i just use the List to get the item...

Comment: What if you set the simplest possible adapter for your viewpager like this: https://gist.github.com/sockeqwe/e269eb34773e9fbb8def
Btw. don't save Fragments in a `List<Fragment>`. Let the `FragmentManager` and `ViewPager` do the job of dealing with Fragments, otherwise you are leaking memory, reuse fragments where they are not supposed to be reused and get into insane fragment states.

Comment: NPE - getPresenter is null :/ what the hell...

Comment: I'm really sorry. I can't see something wrong in your code. However, Mosby seems to work correctly as already discussed here https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues/103
A last advice for debugging is: override `onCreateView()` in `OverviewFragment` and set a break point in there. then step into `super.onCreateView()` and so on. This will create the presenter. Debugging Mosby internals shouldn't be to complicated. Do the same for `onDestroyView()` in `OverviewFragment` (override and set a break point for debugging). This will destroy / detach the presenter ...

Comment: I think i have found the error. Thanks for your help!! I have not implemented the `onCreateView`method and therefore your/mosby's `onViewCreated` method is never called. And then the presenter is null. After adding a layout everything is working fine. And such things keeps a hours.... wtf

Comment: omg ... so true ... I will check if I can add some runtime checks for that ... It would be great if you  cananswer your own question here to Providence help for others struggling in that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the `onCreateView` method and provide a layout. Otherwise the presenter ist null and mosby will throw a NPE for this.